# I want to list users and all user's comments in MongoDB. Is it possible?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to list the users and search for comments in another collection using the same query.

That's my users Schema:

```
Schema({
    cod: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
})
```

And that's my comments Schema:

```
Schema({
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'users'
    },
    post: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'posts'
    },
    comment: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
})
```

I want get some like this:

```
 {
    _id: 5eee97c18b83e338bcbfa8f9,
    name: 'Cool Name',
    cod: 'CN001',
    comments: [{
         _id: ObjectId(...)
         post: ObjectId(...),
         comment: 'comment 1'
        },
        {
         _id: ObjectId(...)
         post: ObjectId(...),
         comment: 'comment 2'
        }
    ]
   
  }
```

is it possible?

Thank you!

Comment: you can use populate https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Answer (score 0):

you might need to change your schema to:

Users:

```
Schema({
    cod: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    comments: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'comments'
    }
})
```

Comments:

```
Schema({
    post: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'posts'
    },
    comment: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    user: { // in case you want to query comments and populate the user
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'users'
    }
})
```

Then query:

```
users.findById({'your user id here'})
.populate({path:'comments',select:['post','comment']})
.then((response)=>{
 // do anything you want with the data here
})
```

Comment: But in this case the comments field in the Users Schema must to be an array, right? And I need to push the comment _id in the comments field.

Comment: yup, its an array of objects more of. just push like $push:{comments:'you user id here'}

Comment: would be great if you accept this answer so it would be helpful for others with the same issue. ty